# Does turning off fast startup stop Windows 8 from writing services to disk?

Tags: windows-8, boot

I have an SSD drive on the way that I plan to install Windows 8 onto, however, I want to minimize disk write to the SSD drive as much as possible.

Does unchecking "Turn on fast startup" in the System Settings prevent Windows 8 from writing running services to disk?

Comment: what do you mean with "prevent Windows 8 from writing running services to disk"? If you disable fast startup, Windows does the "old-school" boot from older Windows versions

Comment: I was looking for that "old-school" shutdown where programs are terminated rather than saved to disk. Wasn't sure whether disabling "Turn on fast startup" is the equivalent to this or whether there is a more complete way to shutdown the OS and not have it write to disk.

Comment: programs are terminated in both shutdowns. Only the kernel, drivers and services where suspended and later resumed. If you want the "old-school" shutdown and boot, disabling fast startup is what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks magicandre1981. That's the exactly what I needed to know.